# Mysql how to copy data from one field to other field in same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I have mysql table as follow:

```
    id      host             url
--------------------------------------
    1                   test.com/index.php
    2                   domain.com/list
    3                   www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

I need output as follow

```
    id      host                 url
------------------------------------------
    1     test.com             test.com/index.php
    2     domain.com           domain.com/list
    3     stackoverflow.com    www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want this to be done in php while inserting the data >>

Comment: What do you want. Update?

Comment: What is your exact question ??????

Comment: `UPDATE table SET host = url`, to answer the question in the title. To extract the host from a URL you either have to find a suitable SQL function/procedure, or you do it in PHP. It would depend on the number of entries you need to process at once and their possible values which one is worth pursuing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, count)`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET host = SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 1);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9e0a/1)

This will make your table looks like:

```
| ID |                  HOST |                                 URL |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |              test.com |                  test.com/index.php |
|  2 |            domain.com |                     domain.com/list |
|  3 | www.stackoverflow.com | www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask |
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table is named `t`:

```sql
UPDATE t
SET host=SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET host = SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 1)
```